# How to create dynamic route link in my navbar

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, routes

I want to create dynamic route on my navbar and redirect it to http://localhost:8000/tasks/nenad page

Web.php

```
Route::get('/tasks/{first_name}', 'Viewercontroller@profile')
    ->middleware('viewer')
    ->name('profile');
```

ViewerController

```
public function profile($first_name) {
    $user = User::whereFirst_name($first_name)->first();
    return view('viewers/tasks', compact('user'));
}
```

Navbar.blade.php:

```
  <li><a href="{{ url(route('profile')) }}">Tasks</a></li>
```

I know that i have to change link on my navbar page but doesn't know how, any help will be great...

Comment: You need to pass the parameter `route('profile', ['first_name' => 'some_name])`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it won't work because your route expects a parameter, so you have to indicate on your navbar.blade.php the parameter you want to pass.

For example I'll assume you have a user saved on $user, then you would do this:

```
route('profile', ['first_name' => $user->name]);
```

You can read more about [URL generation on Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

Comment: Hmmm thanks for answer but it returned me to blank page(page not find).So i guess i have to give value to $variable.So i have to do that in controller ? Really sorry for this kind of question but i'm new in this.Really thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $variable. Can you be more specific please, what was the url generated after clicking your href?

Comment: I mean the $user. I get this url : http://localhost:8000/tasks after i clicked href

Comment: if you dont have a variable named $user it will not work ofcourse! I was just using that as an example to show you since you didn't provide what info was avaiable to you inside your view. Try this: route('profile', ['first_name' => 'use_a_real_variable']);

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CnSAQBF This is ViewerController where i declared $user

Comment: I dont understand, what you need to do is pass the first name to your route as I explained, if you get the url /tasks after clicking the link it means that $user is not defined IN THAT VIEW, your controller is what comes after so it has nothing to do. Your problem is THE ROUTE, you need to pass a NAME as  a variable/string whatever you want I showed you both ways

Comment: Hmmm ok, really thanks for answers. I tried with first method(['first_name' => $user->name])  and currently my link is working while i'm on http://localhost:8000/tasks/nenad page but it doesn't work at http://localhost:8000/home url or any other url .Hmm really strange

Comment: Nope, not strange, its because on the other views your $user variable isn't set, if what you want is to redirect the user to their own profile you can do something like this: ['first_name' => Auth::user()->name],

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i spent whole day in solving of this problem.You helped me a lot.Whish you all best !!! :) :)